# Puma deployment issue with Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, puma

I'm trying to deploy my application to Heroku using Puma.  This is my first time using Puma, as this is my first attempt at a "production quality" application.  I've added puma as described [in the dev center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server) but I'm running into a no method error once deployed.  Here's my error from the logs: `config/puma.rb:5:in _load_from': undefined method preload_app!' for #<Puma::Configuration::DSL:0x007f89e2686140> (NoMethodError)`

I used the suggested configuration in my `config\puma.rb`:

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  # Worker specific setup for Rails 4.1+
  # See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#on-worker-boot
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

as shown in the error above, it seems Heroku has a problem with the `preload_app!` command.  I'm stuck and don't know where to go from here - I have a feeling I somehow miscreated the file - i.e. I just made a new file in my editor rather than from the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how we set `config/puma.rb` up on Heroku using Rails 4.1.0

```
workers Integer(ENV['PUMA_WORKERS'] || 3)
threads Integer(ENV['MIN_THREADS']  || 1), Integer(ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 16)

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  # worker specific setup
  ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
    config = ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env] ||
             Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
    config['pool'] = ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 16
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)
  end
end
```

We keep the workers and threads to a minimum (we are on the free plan).

When I restart our dyno, I get this output in the logs:

```
2015-03-.. app[web.1]: [3] Puma starting in cluster mode...
2015-03-... app[web.1]: [3] * Version 2.9.1 (ruby 2.1.5-p273), codename: Team High Five
2015-03-... app[web.1]: [3] * Min threads: 1, max threads: 3
2015-03-... app[web.1]: [3] * Environment: production
2015-03-... app[web.1]: [3] * Process workers: 2
2015-03-... app[web.1]: [3] * Preloading application
```

Comment: I see you've used `preload_app!` as well, any ideas on the error I'm getting?

Comment: It probably conflicts with phased restart, but I'm not completely sure.

Comment: I conceptually understand what preload_app does, but given my application is remarkably light, should I drop that command?

Comment: I would try that and also restart your dyno `heroku ps:restart --remote <remote>` and check the log for how puma is starting up. `heroku logs --tail --remote <remote>`That can give you info on if `preload_app!` is conflicting in any way. But I'm a little puzzled by this error.